# Gridview or similar functionality in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Currently am fetching user Entered comments from DB and displaying in View as below

```
foreach (var item in Model.lstCommet)
                                    {
        <span class="comment_time">@Html.formattedDateTime(item.dTime.Value) </span>
        <span> : </span>
         <span class="comment_body">@item.displayComments</span> 
         <br />
        }
```

And am planning to add EDIT and DELETE functionality for each items. How can i do this in MVC ?

Like if user clicks Edit it should make a textbox and after editing they submit.

In asp.net we use gridview or other stuffs and capture. how do i do here ?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't mind paying, kendoui for mvc has some great functionality http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-editing.  Otherwise there are quite a few free JavaScript grids you can implement with a little work.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MVC.  first you have to do all html part yourself here. thats what MVC is all about

1) you can do it with Jquery, creat a form make it hidden and then on click of edit button load values to textboxes etc and make the form visisble

2) Create a separte view for edit and on edit click go to that view with required Id etc and load the form in edit mode and do saving etc.

you can use [WebGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) also which will help you creating grid, not with all you need, but its something

Comment: So that will lot of new stuff we need to add !